# Recursion with lambda expressions

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the lambda expressions. My code snippet should be using a position of a tree and do the traversal with the code. I think I might be looking it at the wrong way. Maybe logic or lack of syntax knowledge of the lambda expressions is what's stopping me of doing what I want.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below my code snippet:

```java
@Override
public void traverseInOrder(Consumer<Position<E>> visit) {
    visit = p -> inOrder(p);
    visit.accept(root);
}

private void inOrder(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {
    BinaryTreeNode<E> t = (BinaryTreeNode<E>) p;
    pt -> {
        inOrder(t.left);
        System.out.println(t.element());
        inOrder(t.right));
    };
}
```

Comment: I have trouble to understand what your problem is. What are you expecting and what is actually happening? What is the question here?

Comment: Are you used to using anonymous classes?

Comment: What I'm doing is creating a way to traverse a binary tree. (not BST) just visit the node and go all the way down to the last node of each branch and start printing the node element. 
What is given in order to solve this, is the first method with Consumer as a parameter which visits nodes in a tree. As asked also, this would be my first, very first approach to anonymous classes and lambda expressions.

Comment: Oracle has an excellent beginners tutorial on lambda expressions and their use here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html  I tried to rework your example, but I have no idea if it will compile, and I think it might just confuse you more.

Comment: You can use https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/08/inorder-traversal-of-binary-tree-in-java-recursion-iteration-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Start with "apply a visitor to a node and all its subnodes", that is:

```java
private void inOrder(Consumer<E> visitor, BinaryTreeNode<E> node) {
    if (node != null) {  // some stop condition
        // TODO traverse left subnode
        // TODO visit actual element
        // TODO traverse right subnode
    }
}
```

and this is called like:

```java
@Override
public void traverseInOrder(Consumer<E> visitor) {
    inOrder(visitor, root);
}
```

which, in turn, can be called like:

```java
traverseInOrder(e -> System.out.println(e));
// or, same as above
traverseInOrder(System.out::println);
```

The first method should be very simple, example:

```java
private void inOrder(Consumer<E> visitor, BinaryTreeNode<E> node) {
    if (node != null) {
        inOrder(visitor, t.left);
        visitor.apply(t.element);
        inOrder(visitor, t.right);
    }
}
```

<sub>*loosely* based on code posted in question, types assumed, not tested</sub>

Note1: if using the `java.util.function.Consumer` class, it should be `visitor.accept(t.element)`

Note2: as commented by [Clashsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4138801/clashsoft), the correct way to declare the `visitor` (both methods) would be as `Consumer<? super E> visitor`. That means that the visitor is a function that takes an argument of type `E` or any supertype of `E` (like an `Consumer<Object>` if `E` is an `Integer`)

Comment: Should be `Consumer<? super E>`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, now all I have to do is understand the algorithm and still study with more examples for lambda. One step at the time and be a better programmer.